# Селектор любого элемента, окончание которого на "__class" (SCSS)?

Tags: css, sass, scss

Как правильно написать селектор (SCSS), который найдет на странице все классы, окончание которых `__class`?

Предположил, что так (не вышло):

```
body *
  {
    &__class
    {
      color: red;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так:

```
[class$="__class"] {
  background: blue;
}
```

```
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col col__class"></div>
<div class="col col__class"></div>
<div class="col col__class"></div>
<div class="col col__class"></div>
<div class="col col__class"></div>
```

Comment: В качестве подстраховки можно добавить селектор `[class*="__class "]` . Это на тот случай если искомый класс будет не в конце атрибута.